# Using RegEx to match inch marker (") to validate feet and inches

Tags: c#, regex

I am coding in C# and am using Substring to break apart my string and then I am using RegEx to check each item in my string. My string that I am breaking apart is for a person's height. I am able to validate the feet, foot maker ('), and inches but am having trouble with the inch marker ("). Here is how I am doing it, and would like to know of a way to use RegEx to validate the inch marker.

The Regex for the inchMarker does not work for checking the " mark. If there is any other way to check the inch marker, I would appreciate the help.

```
bool footMarker = Regex.IsMatch(hght.Substring(1, 1), @"^[']$");
bool inchMarker = Regex.IsMatch(hght.Substring(4,1), @"^[&quot;]$");
bool footVal = Regex.IsMatch(hght.Substring(0, 1), @"^[4-7]$");
bool inchVal1 = Regex.IsMatch(hght.Substring(2, 1), @"^[0-1]$");
bool inchVal2 = Regex.IsMatch(hght.Substring(3, 1), @"^[0-9]$");
```

Comment: You need to give some sample data here. This is just patterns. Also are you sure you're getting `&quot;` and not things like `"` or `”`?

Comment: The height needs to be in the following format #'##", or 5'04", 6'06", etc. When I use the Regex for the inchMarker ("), Visual Studio is reading it as follows (/"). So for example, if I enter in 5'04" and step through VS, it reads it as follows: 5'04/". If finds all of the other bools to be true, but the inch marker false.

Comment: That doesn’t make much sense. Are you sure it’s not a backslash in a literal? `"5'04\""`

Comment: Right, but if you add some known-good input to your question it will help people *considerably* when verifying their answers are correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool inchMarker = Regex.IsMatch(hght.Substring(4,1), @"^[&quot;]$");
```

`&quot;` is an HTML escape for a quotation mark. Judging by your debugger comment, you don’t have HTML and just wanted to include a regular quotation mark in your string literal. In a verbatim string literal, that’s done with two consecutive `"`s:

```
@"^[""]$"
```